# Arduino millis not work

Tags: c, arduino

I have written a huge program for Arduino.
I have tested each function individually, and all go fine except the function where I need millis().

Now carry the code block that I encounter any difficulties.

the variable T contains the number in seconds for this is multiplied by 1000

```
void onResistance(){
  Input = sensors.getTempC(tempSensor);
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); // prime the pump for the next one - but don't wait

  digitalWrite(RelayPin, HIGH);
  //more code
  Input = sensors.getTempC(tempSensor);
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); // prime the pump for the next one - but don't wait

  if(Input<Setpoint){ onResistance(); }
  else{ digitalWrite(RelayPin, LOW); istru++; return ; }

  return ;
}

void statTemp(){
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if(currentMillis - previousMillis > ttemp){

      previousMillis = currentMillis;

      Input = sensors.getTempC(tempSensor);
      sensors.requestTemperatures();
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(F("T. Att.:"));
      lcd.print(Input);
      lcd.write(1);
      lcd.print(F("C"));

      if (Input<Setpoint) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin, HIGH);
        statTemp();
      } else if(Input>Setpoint || Input == Setpoint) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin, LOW);
        statTemp(); }

    } else if(currentMillis - previousMillis < ttemp) { playShortBeep(); istru++; return; }
    return ;
}

void startFan(){
  Input = sensors.getTempC(tempSensor);
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); // prime the pump for the next one - but don't wait

  digitalWrite(FAN_PIN, HIGH);
  //more code
  Input = sensors.getTempC(tempSensor);
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); // prime the pump for the next one - but don't wait

  if(Input>Tm){ startFan(); }
  else{ digitalWrite(FAN_PIN, LOW); istru++; return ; }

  return ;
}

void controll(){


  if(!start)
    return ;

  if(start){
    if(istru==0){
      onResistance();
    }
    if(istru==1){
      ttemp = (T * 1000) + millis() ;
      statTemp();
    }
    if(istru==2){
      startFan();
    }
    if(istru==3){
      start =false;
      opState = OFF;
      playShortBeep();
      playShortBeep();
      playShortBeep();
      istru=0;
    }
  }
  delay(100);
  return ;
}
```

I need for the time T the function statTemp remains running conducting checks if written in it.
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

So you want to stay in the function statTemp() until time T has passed?
Then something like this might work

```
void statTemp(){
    unsigned long currentMillis;
    unsigned long enteringMillis = millis();
    while (((currentMillis = millis()) -enteringMillis) < T)
    {
        if(currentMillis - previousMillis > ttemp){
        etc etc etc....
    }
    return ;
}
```

Notice the MIGHT. I don't know if millis is updated at every timer interrupt or just in the loop function; in the latter case, you will be stuck forever in the function.

Consequently i suggest you not to do this, but think at another approach: an FSM which handles the function to be executed. It's a cleaner way to proceed and less error-prone.

Bye

EDIT:
Here is a complete working example. In this example, the function `myfunc` is executed for 10 seconds; during this time the board performs some actions (in this example serial output). When 10 seconds pass, the program goes on, thus repeating the loop function.

```
unsigned long previousTime;
void myfunc();

void setup() {                
  Serial.begin(9600);     
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("I'm in the loop function");
  myfunc();
}

void myfunc()
{
  unsigned long currentTime;
  unsigned long enteringTime = millis();
  while(((currentTime = millis()) - enteringTime) < 10000)
  {
    if(currentTime - previousTime > 1000)
    {
      previousTime = currentTime;
      Serial.println("I'm in the custom function");
    }
  }
}
```

HOWEVER my suggestion is still the same: instead of blocking the execution inside of a function, use a finite state machine; it's much more flexible and easier to understand, implement and edit.

Comment: T is a global variable. I calculate the time when T ends in this way ttemp =  ( T *  1000 )  + millis ()  ;  and I use ttemp in the if

Comment: Sorry, then i can't clearly see what you need.. Can you please tell me what does not work, what is the expected behaviour and what you instead obtain.